# javadoc: "package [...] does not exist" for external references without docs

Tags: java, javadoc

I am using javadoc to generate my documentation. I have my own classes, and two external jars:

- json simple, where I have the source and could generate javadocs
- a proprietary library, where i have no chance to get the source or docs.

When I run the javadoc tool, I get multiple errors:

- "**package [...] does not exist**" whenever I import a class of the external libraries.
- "**cannot find symbol [...]**" whenever I use a class of the external libraries.

This is of course correct, as javadoc has no idea where to find sources or docs for these classes.

But, I do not want these messages to show, as I want to be able to recognize at first glance, if everything worked as intended. Right now, I have to look through hundred lines of "known errors" to find any other errors or warnings.

How can I fix or suppress the errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I just needed to add the external libraries to the classpath, as described here:
[Javadoc Documentation: classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#classpath)
Example: `-classpath D:/folder/lib.jar`