# Generated javadoc for Android project is empty

Tags: android, javadoc, java-11

Generating the javadoc worked perfectly fine with Java 8 but does not work with the newly bundled Java 11 in Android Studio.

I get errors like `error: package ... does not exist` or `error: cannot find symbol`, but these are all files and references that should not be public or documented in any case.

As additional info: I am working on an SDK (thats why some classes need to be not documented) and here is the task that creates the javadoc.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.
And yes I read this post: [javadoc: "package [...] does not exist" for external references without docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075521/javadoc-package-does-not-exist-for-external-references-without-docs) but it is not applicable, since the files that are causing the issue are not third party.

```
task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) { 

    options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC
    options.encoding = "utf-8"
    failOnError = false
    source = variant.javaCompiler.source
    def androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    doFirst {
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(androidJar)
    }
    options {
        links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/"
        linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
    }
    // and then there are includes of packages and files
}
```

**Edit:**
When removing the includes the javadoc is created without an issue, but of course for all the classes.

**Edit 2:**
Found an interim solution by ignoring source errors.

```
options.addStringOption('-ignore-source-errors', '-quiet')
```

Comment: Ever tried flipping the classpath entries? Without `--info` or `--debug` output, this is nothing one could answer; besides, you are linking to Java 7 documentaion, which appears to be  non-sense. You're actually shooting yourself in the foot with switch `-quiet`. And in Android Studio, one doesn't even need Gradle, but there's a dialog to generate docs.

Comment: What do you mean with flipping the classpath entries? And regarding the need for a gradle task: it is used during our build process so we don't generate javadoc manually.

Comment: The files on class-path likely all depend on `android.jar`, which might be loaded after it had been attempted to load them... and if you reject the suggestion with Android Studio, which may help to fix the task, one probably cannot help. Just get rid of that `-quiet` switch; this is the very last one wants to use when it's not working. Currently your error description is alike "it's not working", which is not an error description.

Comment: Removed the `-quiet` flag and generated the javadoc with AS as per your suggestion and it worked. So I had a hunch and removed the includes from the gradle task and that also worked. I am a bit confused as to why it doesn't work if I set specific files.

Comment: My confusion comes rather from the fact that it worked perfectly fine with Java 8.